# How to install Django through subversion in Windows 7?

Tags: python, django, svn

How do I install Django through subversion in Windows 7? I got SlikSVN installed right now, but I get an error when trying to run the command:

`svn co https://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/ django-trunk`

```
svn: E160013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://code-djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk'
svn: E160013: The path "/svn/django/trunk" doesn't exist
```

The link is probably not updated. But is there an updated link somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is no longer using subversion, the new repository [is hosted on github](https://github.com/django/django). You *can* [access it via subversion](https://github.com/blog/1178-collaborating-on-github-with-subversion), but I would recommend using git instead, or [using a release tarball](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/).